# What is the verb form of tuition

Tags: verb-forms

I what to know whether there is any verb form of tuition or not.
Suppose I teach some students in their home as a private tutor.
Can I say that : " I shall tuition you tomorrow"

Comment: Welcome to ELL and thanks for your question. Your question would be better if you had included the research you have done on your own. Here is a [**link**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) specifically about asking a good question. We hope you will ask more questions!

Comment: You could use *tuition* as a verb, but you might be the only person doing so. The *Oxford English Dictionary* (OED)  lists  'tuition'  only as a noun. In North America it is usually used as a short version  of *tuition fees*. Note *Webster's American English Dictionary* (1828)  'In our colleges, the tuition is from thirty to forty dollars a year'–which the OED gives as an example of tuition meaning *tuition-fees*.

Comment: @user356595 Do you want to say: "I shall charge you a fee tomorrow" or "I shall teach you tomorrow" ?

Comment: I guess you could say *I will 'tuit' you tomorrow*, along the lines of the verb 'to intuit'  (Cf 'intuition'). But again, this is not a word in usage. So, yes, *to tutor* or *to teach/instruct*.

Answer (score 3):

### Tutor

**Tuition** comes from the verb "to tutor", so you would say

> I shall tutor you tomorrow

**Tuition** is very commonly alluded to money and costs/fees... since we only ever see the word tuition next to the word fees. i.e "tuition and fees", "tuition fees"

> How much is tuition?
>
> I'm not paying such high tuition.

Spoken, and also written, this is a completely acceptable usage of the word, but in my opinion, the word **tuition** does not indicate anything of monetary value.  You can't pay for things with tuition.

### You pay *for* the tuition.

This is to say that **tuition** is the action of tutoring.  Being mentored, guided, guarded and taught is what tuition is. That is what you pay for.

Comment: @user356595 I don't know a single native speaker of American English who would use 'tuition' to mean 'the act of tutoring someone, or rather, teaching/mentoring'.  This  is a valid definition, but most American English speakers do not know that.  The only 'tuition' I'm familiar is the money you pay to receive an education.

Comment: Also 'tuition' does not come from the verb 'to tutor'. According to the *Oxford English Dictionary* it comes straight from Anglo-Norman/Old French from  the corresponding noun form(s)  of  those languages.

Comment: I've updated my answer @AlanCarmack.

Comment: Tuition: "The action or business of teaching a pupil or pupils; the function of a tutor or instructor (see tutor n.); teaching, instruction."  (OED) See also [Oxford Online dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tuition), taking note of the "North American" meaning.

Comment: +1 as I could *never* think of 'tutor' as a verb until I read this! Well, in InE, we have *tuition classes!* as well! 'Tuition' here means 'coaching classes', charges you pay to a tutor is 'tuition fees.'

Answer (score -2):

I read it used like this: ". . .this inherent talent still had to be nurtured through tuition." 
The Colors of All Cattle; No. 1 Ladies Detective Agency,  (2018, Pantheon)
by Alexander McCall Smith. 
He is a Scott and this series takes place in Botswana. His use here of the word "tuition" is why I looked it up.

Comment: That's not a verb form.